# Nuclear Fallout

Tags: biochemistry, ions, nuclear, radioactivity

If there was a nuclear explosion and years later I come out of a fallout shelter like in the popular game series Fallout, what elements would react to the radiation in a way that could harm humans and what happens to humans when they interact with these substances?

Comment: While this is interesting question, it too broad and imprecise. Situation would depend on lots of factors.

Comment: IMO it would be much different question. I think earlier was better but you should narrow it down

Comment: We can discuss it in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table)

Comment: @Mithoron I think I'll leave this question as is and ask a separate and more thought out question later. I realized the question is completely different now but I'm still interested in what answers to this question would be. Maybe if stackoverflow added a tree of topics instead of separate tags it would be possible to convert broad questions into topics with an array of subtopics and/or questions inside.

Comment: The whole SE model is to have one clear question, and provide answers to that question. Multiple queries in one question do not fit the model.

Comment: As for the core question, the 'harmful' elements (isotopes) are either generated directly in the nuclear explosion, or are part of the directly generated isotope decay chains (i.e. daughter products). If I recall properly, Cs, Sr, and I are major issues for humans since they are taken up by the body resulting in internal rad dose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the best examples would be [Bikini Atoll](https://marshallislands.llnl.gov/bikini.php).

> Today, the key residual fallout radionuclides of potential radiological concern include cesium-137 and strontium-90 and, to a lesser extent, plutonium isotopes and americium-241.
>
> The most important pathway for human exposure to residual fallout contmaination is ingestion of cesium-137 contained in locally grown food crop products such as coconuts, Pandanus, and breadfruit

According to the [CDC's Radioisotope Brief: Cesium-137](http://emergency.cdc.gov/radiation/isotopes/cesium.asp)

> External exposure to large amounts of Cs-137 can cause burns, acute radiation sickness, and even death. Exposure to Cs-137 can increase the risk for cancer because of exposure to high-energy gamma radiation. Internal exposure to Cs-137, through ingestion or inhalation, allows the radioactive material to be distributed in the soft tissues, especially muscle tissue, exposing these tissues to the beta particles and gamma radiation and increasing cancer risk.